# @media queries for responsive design (mobile/tablet/desktop)

Tags: html, css

Above is my CSS for my question.
Is my CSS incorrect to display just one class per screen size?

I have been doing a million different variants of this (of course, this is an exaggeration) and I keep ending up with slightly different, but incorrect results.

This time I ended up with all 3 classes showing until the screen hit 480 pixels.
Then only my `.desktop` class showed.

```css
    /*Desktop Query*/
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        .desktop {
            display: none;
        }
        .mobile, .tablet {
            display: block;
        }
    }

    /*Mobile Query*/
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .mobile {
            display: none;
        }
        .desktop, .tablet {
            display: block;
        }
    }

    /*Tablet Query*/
    @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
        .tablet {
            display: none;
        }
        .mobile, .desktop {
            display: block;
        }
    }
```

Here is my HTML:

```html
    <div class="mobile">
        <main>
            <h2> </h2>
            <p> </p>
        </main>
    </div>
```

Comment: <div class="mobile"   <main>   <h2> </h2> <p> </p> </main> </div>    This is the format for my html for all 3 spots (the other 2 being class="desktop" and class="tablet")                  Sorry about the comment extra and it's formatting, was having trouble including HTML code into the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code not displaying correctly is that you've literally inverted the display 100% incorrectly from what it should be:

```css
    /**Desktop Query*/
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      .desktop {
        display: block;
      }
      .mobile, .tablet {
        display: none;
      }
    }

    /*Tablet Query*/
    @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
      .tablet {
        display: block;
      }
      .mobile, .desktop {
        display: none;
      }
    }
    
    /*Mobile Query*/
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      .mobile {
        display: block;
      }
      .desktop, .tablet {
        display: none;
      }
    }
```

Note that I've also moved the tablet query to above the mobile query, as media queries will execute **sequentially** from top to bottom, which would explain why you were having strange results before.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you for this so much. I will move my queries around immediately. My other issue I was having was that I had 3 <main> elements and I guess you can only have 1, so I have fixed that as well. Yet again, THANK YOU SO MUCH, no more yelling contests with my dogs because of you.

Comment: Glad to hear this answer solved the problem for you. Please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly :)

Comment: I have now, and yet again thank you for the help/guidance. I've been losing hairs over this.

Comment: Honestly, it's no problem! Though you may want to look into logic in media queries (https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/); just remember that they flow sequentially, and you'll be fine :) Also, remember to actually think about what you want to display -- you **want** to display the mobile div in a mobile resolution, for example ;)

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up your example so you can make more sense out of it. It works fine just by doing this:

```
/*Desktop Query*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background: black;
  }
}

/*Mobile Query*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    background-color: tomato;
  }
}

/*Tablet Query*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width:768px) {
  body {
    background: pink;
  }
}
```